# Custom/Distributed documentation of changes with Doxygen

Tags: tcl, doxygen, documentation-generation

I am attempting to get the following feature working with Doxygen.

Is this possible, and how best to do this?

We are working with an existing Tcl codebase that came with an EDA tool, a lot of which is code that gets 'sourced' and is not necessarily organized in procedures.  There are numerous improvements/modifications that we have applied to this code base.  An example customization would be of the form "allow feature X to be controlled with new configuration variable Y", and involves modifications made to fileA, fileB, and fileC.

I have Doxygen parsing the entire code base.  Besides standard language documentation I am looking to extract a list of all customizations we have made, including which files were modified (and approx line number), what changes were made in each file, capture of the modified code from each files, and pointer to the file listing and line number where the modification was made.

I expect this to require custom Doxygen comments/tags in fileA, fileB, and fileC, and the closest I managed to get is by placing the following at each location where something is modified in fileA fileB and fileC:

```
##
# \page custom_mypage1 Customization enabling control of X with variable Y
# 
# This is a test comment 1
#
```

This allows for collecting the comments from the three locations, but I can't figure out how to:

1. include portion of the source code that follows, and
2. how to have the generated documentation include references to file/line number of where the comment came from

Answer (score 0):

Using `xrefitem` instead of `page` would provide the link between the summary page and source.

To include a code snippet in the page, `snippet` may help.

Example:

```
/**
\xrefitem customization1 "Change for 1" "Changes for customization1"
Description of change.
\snippet CurrentSourceFile.cpp change1
*/
//! [change1]
Modified code here...
//! [change1]
```

Comment: Eric, this looks very promising.  Without a \page reference, where would Doxygen place the the content of comment marked with \xrefitem?

Comment: Doxygen creates a page for each distinct xrefitem "tag" ("customization1" in my example)

Comment: I can't seem to get DoxyGen to generate anything related to \xrefitem or even \todo.  It parses the files with these directives and includes other extracted information from them.  I have all of the following set in configuration:
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES

Comment: It appears that DoxyGen only captures \xrefitem and its derivatives (example \todo) if they appear associated with a recognized code element (class, procedure, namespace, ext).  Any time the \xrefitem stands on its own, or even when it is inside a \page it is ignored by DoxyGen.  @ric-malenfant, any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: Sorry @eric, I misspelled your name above.